# Explain example in Python with class

Tags: python

Can anyone explain me the following example?
How does this gets all the elements from the for loop and not only the last one?

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(SUITS[i], RANKS[j]) 
                      for i in range (0, len(SUITS)) 
                      for j in range (0, len(RANKS))]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a really terrible way to do this - looping by index is slow, inefficient, and hard to read. What you really want is `[Card(suit, rank) for suit, rank in itertools.product(SUITS, RANKS)]`.

Comment: a crappy python way of looping

Comment: The more pythonic version would be `[ Card(suit, rank) for suit in SUITS for rank in RANKS]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list comprehension with nested loops. It can be translated to:

```
self.cards = []
for i in range(0, len(SUITS)):
    for j in range(0, len(RANKS)):
        self.cards.append(Card(SUITS[i], RANKS[j]))
```

It could be simplified further though, by looping over `SUITS` and `RANKS` directly:

```
self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in SUITS for rank in RANKS]
```

or you can use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to replace the nested loops:

```
from itertools import product

self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for suit, rank in product(SUITS, RANKS)]
```

Comment: Hmmmm Did I get the loop backwards? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @qwertynl: It matters; list comprehension loops are executed as if nested from left to right. The order of the cards in your version will differ.

Comment: I would recommend using [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) over nested loops. (`[Card(suit, rank) for suit, rank in itertools.product(SUITS, RANKS)]`). It's both more efficient and readable.

Comment: @Lattyware: This is from a learning Python book (Dive into Python, IIRC), so `itertools.product()` is perhaps getting a little advanced, but I added it anyway.

Comment: A function call is more advanced than multi-loop list comps? I find those indecipherable at the best of times.

Comment: @Lattyware: I mean that it deviates further from what the book is covering at that time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little confusing but it translates to this pseudocode:

```
self.cards = [];
for i in range (0, len(SUITS))
   for j in range (0, len(RANKS))
        self.cards.append(Card(SUITS[i], RANKS[j]));
```

Basically a loop within a loop.

It is much easier to read in my example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's basically a couple nested for loops:

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for i in range(0, len(SUITS):
            for j in range(0, len(RANKS):
                self.cards.append(Card(SUITS[i], RANKS[j]))
```